# List Navigation elements from left to right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to list navigation elements from left to right like this:
 `Start   Über    Weitere   Kontakt` instead of this
`Start`

`Über`

`Weitere`

`Kontakt`

but it doesn't seem to work. I have already tried using `float: left;`
,`display:inline;` and `list-style: none;` on `#navigation li` but it just stays the same.

This is the navigation structure in the index.html

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 100px;
}

#navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#navigation li {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Start</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Über</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Weitere</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: `#navigation` selects an element with the ID of navigation. You're using a class. So either change the selector to `.navigation`, or change the class to an ID like `<ul id="navigation">`

Comment: You generally don't want to mix flex with absolute positioning. In fact, don't use absolute positioning _ever_ unless you really understand why you need it. It's rarely a good idea. You also wouldn't specify inline display for flex elements, usually.

Comment: Classes are usually best for CSS, so that it's reusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given ul a `class="navigation"`

But the problem is that in your CSS you are using the id selector
`#navigation`

Jsut change it to class selector:
`.navigation`

Also, to achieve your goal position is not required.

The Following Code is Sufficient.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navigation li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Start</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Über</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Weitere</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, here is the solution.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.logo{
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.navigation {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.navigation li {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"><a href="#">Logo</a></div>
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Start</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Über</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Weitere</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```